# How to automatically restore ms sql database from bak file to rds from s3 using lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Periodic .bak files are uploaded to S3, I need to create a lambda function which invokes on .bak upload and automatically restores .bak file to related RDS instance which is running. Can any one help me with automation part(Python code)

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @fuzzi yes, I solved it. execute the following procedure

exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database
@restore_db_name='database_name',
@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/bakup_file'

Comment: @Kavyashree, how did you establish connect from Lambda to rds to run the above procedure?